# Retrieving selected image only from listview

Tags: c#, image, listview, selecteditem

I am working with C#.

- Logic:-

1-Retrieve multiple images path from database. **(done)**

```
        OpenConnection();
        DataTable dtp = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand adp1 = new SqlCommand("Select pictures_path from Folder_Pix" , sqlcon);
        SqlDataReader sdr = adp1.ExecuteReader();
```

2-Then set that images on listview. **(done)**

```
        imglist = new ImageList();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            Bitmap img = new Bitmap(sdr[0].ToString());
            imglist.Images.Add(img);
            this.listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
            imglist.ImageSize = new Size(60, 50);
            this.listView1.LargeImageList = imglist;
        }
       for (int j = 0; j < imglist.Images.Count; j++)
        {
           ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
           item.ImageIndex = j;
           this.listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

*where sdr is SqlDataReader.

3- Retrieve selected image on double click. **(Error)**

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Form2 obj = new Form2();

       foreach (Image img in listView1.SelectedItems[0].ImageList.Images)
        {
          obj.pictureBox1.Image = img;
          MessageBox.Show("pause");
          obj.Show();
        }

    }
```

Whenever i click on an image, it returns all image-1.

In my case, their are 4 images added to ListView.Whenever i click on an image, Form2 get opened 3 times, displaying 2nd, 3rd and fourth image!

I tested FocusedItem instead of SelectedItems.But the result are same.

What am i doing wrong? i tried every possible way. I am continuously working on it since 8 hours.

Comment: you have a foreach loop and arent testing for the current index

Comment: What about for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `foreach` you are iterating through the entire `ImageList` and not the `SelectedItem`. Basically, `list_img.SelectedItems[0].ImageList` is a reference to the entire `ImageList` and not a specific Image. The Image is specified by the `ImageIndex`. Try this instead:

```
private void list_img_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (list_img.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        var item = list_img.SelectedItems[0];
        var img = item.ImageList.Images[item.ImageIndex];
        var f = new Form2();
        f.pictureBox1.Image = img;
        MessageBox.Show("pause");
        f.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: doesn't Contain a definition for FirstOrDefault().

Comment: Ok, it seems the collection doesn't support Linq. I'll edit the answer.